# E/AppWidgetHostView: Package name not found

Tags: android, android-appwidget, package-name

I write an `android` App Widget and it works fine. After some time I had to change its package name But it works well yet.  I already had `getPackageName`, and it prints the correct package name in the log, and still sometimes after I upgrade the app (or just run it on the device from `AndroidStudio`) the widget disappears. Later it got back after another upgrade.
this is my logcat :
06-20 14:59:31.208 23516-23516/? E/InstalledAppDetails: Exception when retrieving package:ir.yasin.dordane.rozshomar_widget

```
android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: ir.yasin.dordane.rozshomar_widget
                                                        at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:115)
                                                        at com.android.settings.applications.InstalledAppDetails.retrieveAppEntry(InstalledAppDetails.java:723)
                                                        at com.android.settings.applications.InstalledAppDetails.refreshUi(InstalledAppDetails.java:758)
                                                        at com.android.settings.applications.InstalledAppDetails.onActivityResult(InstalledAppDetails.java:595)
                                                        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6139)
                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3564)
                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3611)
                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:147)
                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1345)
                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
```